# need API for send log messages to server

Tags: c++, c, logging, network-programming

is there API in C/C++ that enable to send log messages reliable?
better if it cross platform

something like
client side:
SEND_LOG(192.168.1.12,"file opened");

server side
string s=RECEIVE();

Comment: There's nothing like this in the standard library. You'd have to implement something like that yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Apache log4cxx

http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/